# Format a note in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am inserting a number of notes into my Google Sheet, but the notes have quite a bit of text, so I want to format them (i.e. reduce the font size, and re-size the note box so the scroll bar isn't required).

Is there any way of formatting notes in Google Sheets?

Comment: did you find any way?

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2018 there seems to be no such option. Although I would like the same